# Deriving identities involving divisor function by equating coefficients in appropriate identities in modular forms

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am trying exercise problems of Apostol modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I am struck on this problem of Ch -6 . 
I am adding its image. 
[image]

I think ratio of modular discriminant should be taken ,  but modular discriminant is a cusp form so constant would be zero ( if I divide by modular form of appropriate weight) .

Can someone please help. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity arise since $E_{12}-E_6^2=k\Delta$, for a constant $k$
you should identify.

Then you have
$$756\tau(n)=65\sigma_{11}(n)+691\sigma_5(n)-691\times252\sum(\text{omitted}).$$
Treating this modulo $691$ gives
$$65\tau(n)\equiv65\sigma_{11}(n)\pmod{691}.$$
As $\gcd(65,691)=1$ then
$$\tau(n)\equiv\sigma_{11}(n)\pmod{691}.$$

Comment: if I put $\tau$ = i$\infty $ in x = exp( 2πi$\tau$) , then both LHS and RHS becomes zero, so I need to use any other constant  , so if I choose comparing coefficients of x when n=1 then I get 65520/691 - 1080 on LHS and 1 on RHS, how did you got k different ? as I am sure the k i got above is wrong.

Comment: Just compare the coefficients of $q$ in the $q$-expansion.

Comment: I think you mean q = exp( 2πi$\tau$) , I have done the same thing which I have written in the comment ,but it is different than what you are getting . Can you please show calculations.

Comment: Write $E_{12}=1+aq+\cdots$ and $E_6=1+bq+\cdots$, Work out $a$ and $b$. Then $k=a-2b$.

Comment: I know this but as I mentioned in above comment my a=65520/691 and 2b =-  1008 and so my k is different.I am adding images in problem of book where Apostol mentions $E_2k$ . Please see them ( I am adding them in original question asked) .

Comment: can you please tell whats your a and b? And please have a look at added image in the problem

Comment: @user686624 Is it clear to you that $E_{12}-E_6^2$ is in $S_{12}(SL_2(Z))$ which is one-dimensional thus it is $=k\Delta$ where $k$ is the coefficient of $q$ ? The remaining part is boring routine, finding the $q$ coefficient of $E_{12},E_6$ , showing $\Delta$ has integer coefficients, find $k$ and see that reducing $\bmod 691$ the obtained equality of formal series is natural, it is not really useful to write the details. You can use pari/gp to automate the process.

Comment: @user686624 You've written down all the $E_k$ up to $E_{14}$. From these, you can read off $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown  yes that were just some calculations. Solved it.